# Offroad, off road, or off-road?

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives

My instincts tell me that the following phrase should be "2014 and newer off-road equipment." When I Google it, I see all of the these: offroad, off road, and off-road. Is there a correct one? Or should I just go with my instinct?

Thanks!

Comment: There are many posts on this site relating to the use of the hyphen with compound adjectives/ phrasal adjectives. This is not an exception and the question *may* face close votes.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, hyphenate multi-word terms (only) when using them as an adjective:

> I took my off-road vehicle off road today.

This particular term is most commonly hyphenated:

From [Google Ngrams *offroad* / *off road* / *off-road*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Offroad%2Coff+road%2Coff-road&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1920):

[image: popularity of offroad vs off road vs off-road]