# Preferred writing (adjective): ‘offshore’ or ‘off-shore’

Tags: compounds, compound-adjectives

I wonder what the preferred writing is of ‘off-shore’/‘offshore’, as an adjective to, e.g., (wind) farm. From the answer given in the [similar question about ‘off-road’/‘offroad’/‘off road’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234351/offroad-off-road-or-off-road), I would guess ‘off-shore’ is appropriate. However, I see ‘offshore’ a lot in this context, for example on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offshore_wind_power. So perhaps ‘offshore’ should not be viewed anymore as a compounding of ‘off’ and ‘shore’, but as a word on its own.

Comment: A simple word search in the dictionaries (Webster's, Collins or Oxford) will give you an answer. Also please do not depend on Wikipedia to make opinions or decide anything.

Comment: @Fahad Shaikh Should we put more faith in Fahad Shaikh than in Wikipedia :)

Comment: Nope, not at all! Put faith only and only in the dictionaries and recognized style guides :)

Answer (score 2):

Following [Fahad Shaik's prompting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377155/preferred-writing-adjective-offshore-or-off-shore#comment884776_377155), I looked at the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-shore), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/offshore) or [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/offshore) dictionaries, finding that *‘offshore’* is the common spelling.